# Keyboard layout went crazy (in Fossa). How to fix?

Tags: keyboard, configuration, layout

My notebook is an Acer Aspire 5, processor Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, and my system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 64 bits, Gnome 3.36.2.
I have kids so I created accounts for each one of them, while I have the only administrator account. We have two keyboard layouts installed, USA English and Portuguese from Portugal, and the user can choose which one to use in all the accounts. One of the kids did something that made the keyboard go crazy and I can’t put it back to normal (many keys are out of place, “p” became “*”, “o” became “6”, etc). All the other accounts were still normal. But then the same kid used one of the other accounts and the same thing happened to the keyboard in this other account.
How can I make the keyboard layout go back to normal?

Comment: maybe pressed NumLock by mistake? try pressing it (with or without Fn depending on your configuration )

Comment: Great! You solved it! Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer to close the thread. Please accept it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You had enabled NumLock wich replaces some keys with NumPad's on your keyboard.

You can disable it by pressing `NumLock` (along with `Fn` depending on your configuration)

[image: laptop keyboard showing numpad]